# Oscillation when oscilloscope is attached to op-amp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I have a simple op-amp circuit (LT6200) designed to amplify a narrow-band signal centered around 1 MHz. The schematics is shown below.

[image]

And below is the simulation in LTSpice

[image]

I have two problems:

1. When I connect an oscilloscope (DS1104) to J1 - output of the op-amp, I see a weird oscillation at the output even when nothing is fed into VIN. The current consumption of the op amp also increases from ~10mA to ~30mA. This does not happen if I connect a logic analyzer (saleae) to the same output.

[image]

2. When I attach the saleae to the input and output, I find that VIN (generated by a sig gen) is only ~1/10 of when I measure it in isolation. But it doesn't seem to be because of current limit (because it happens regardless of amplitude)

Comment: You've got this beautiful piece of software that KiCad is, with an excellent symbol editor, and yet instead of copying an existing op-amp symbol and adapting it to the part you have, you chose to draw it as... a block? Also, simple circuits like this should be drawn using continuous lines for all connections. The way you've drawn the schematic is misappropriating the schematic tool for a netlist editor. You're using graphical symbols and then just sprinkling them with net names instead of drawing actual wires...

Comment: As it stands, the circuit diagram is utterly unreadable. I'm not even sure what the circuit was supposed to do in the first place. Can you please explain what you're trying to do, so that we can ascertain whether you're not making up some elaborate solution to a very simple problem? (A.k.a. [the XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info))

Comment: Assuming that your circuit is intended to do what it does, could it be that the parasitic capacitance of the probe is making your amp oscillate? If you can find the equivalent probe input cap and put it in your simulation, what happens then?

Comment: @Designalog Thanks for your comment. It does seem to have oscillation when I add a 1 nF capacitor to the output - what would be a good workaround for this?

Comment: Your photo suggests that you've probed with a 1X probe. Does a 10X attenuator probe deter oscillations? A different problem: Sometimes probe grounding alligator currents cause radiation back to input - shortening the probe's ground connection may help. When you do these tests, terminate the circuit's input with a resistor equivalent of the source's driving impedance.

Comment: @user3602697 are you supposed to be driving 1nF? If not, then that's not a useful insight. How about ~10pF-20pF, does that make your amp oscillate? If you're using a 1x probe, going to a 10x one might solve your issue.

Comment: It's a sensing circuit, so I am amplifying signals by a piezo element - which I think it means I will not know what my output capacitance would be exactly?

Comment: @user3602697 your amplifier is supposed to be driving something. If it is just a demonstrator to drive the probe to see the output in an oscilloscope, then that's your load. Simulate with it. No amplifier can drive any arbitrary load without instability.

Comment: "a narrow-band signal centered around 1 MHz" How "narrow" is "narrow-band"? We're engineers here, just tell us what input filter response you want, e.g. "6th order Bessel, Rin=..., 1MHz center, Bandpass width=..." etc.

Comment: It was going to drive an ADC I suppose

Comment: @user3602697 any circuit is always designed to drive some kind of load, otherwise we're designing blindly. Even if this load is poorly defined, there must be a model you could assume for your load, or a worst case one.

Comment: @user3602697 Please show how you've assembled that circuit. And tell us how you're going to tune it - because tuning it you will be, Yoda says. You'll need either adjustable inductors or adjustable tweaker capacitors in parallel with the fixed capacitors. The capacitors should be C0G or Mica. The inductors can be probably scrounged from IF filters from old radios. Otherwise, they can be air-wound.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a simple op-amp circuit (LT6200) designed to amplify a narrow-band signal centered around 1 MHz. The schematics is shown below.

I'd be shy of using the term "simple" when the thing is complex enough not to work :)

First of all, let's redraw the circuit so that it may be readable. That's how it should have looked, more-or-less:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f20Jlc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the problems are easier to see. Obvious stuff:

1. The C3-L3 part of the filter doesn't do anything since it is not loaded. R5 provides DC bias only and is otherwise way too high of a resistance to act as a load.
2. LT6200 has a basic bipolar input stage and is not a high-impedance part. It needs a *strong* input bias. 100kΩ is orders of magnitude too high. A hot LT6200 will dump almost 0.1mA through the input (order of magnitude)!

So, as far as AC behavior is concerned, C3-L3-R4 are approximately a short circuit.

R1 seems to suggest that the input source impedance is <<1Ω, so R1 would be the sole source of input impedance to the LC filter network. Did you design the LC filter network with 1Ω source impedance? Is the source of VIN very low compared to R1?

Let's say that you've used a filter design tool to get a 6th-order LC bandpass filter for 50Ω source and load impedance. We'll now reverse-engineer what response you may have been looking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f986lw.png)</sup>

So, it looks like you got yourself a 1.25MHz bandpass, Bessel-ish response.

In this "simple" circuit, even the input filter section is not doing what it's supposed to :)

Let's set up a 50Ω input/output, 1MHz center, 50kHz -3dB bandwidth filter, using [Elsie](http://tonnesoftware.com/elsie.html). We may as well add an input buffer then, so that the input impedance is higher than 50Ω if that would be of some help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faKbBL.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

So, we know more-or-less what you want as far as the input section response. Now let's see what's going on with the feedback section.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f27c7K.png)</sup>

It looks like a generic bandpass, except with the LT6200 it will add gain since it attenuates quite a bit:

[image]
[image]

Now, LT6200 is a fairly low-input-impedance part. Think 1MΩ and tens of μA of bias current. It is designed for high frequency use. A 100kΩ bias network will make it unhappy. Assuming you want x10 gain (20dBV), the complete circuit would look roughly as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnsWMI.png)</sup>

The overall response is approximately:

[image]
[image]

There should be no oscillation with the approximately 15pF load presented by the **10x** oscilloscope probe. It will generally help to add a 40Ω series resistance on the output. It will combine with the LT6200's output impedance of about 10Ω @ 1MHz to provide a "standard" 50Ω output.

Cheap oscilloscope probes are switchable. That's a bad idea in practice. Buy a fixed x10 probe - it can be used, as well as a used x1 probe. That way you'll avoid problems.

With the 40Ω series resistor on the output, even a 1x probe won't destabilize the op-amp.

If you wanted to cut down on the noise of 6200 (not that it's a problem here), you could put a different filter in the feedback network.